# What's a good way to have a PHP class mirror SQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to learn PHP and have chosen to make a simple project tracker as an exercise.

I can't find a nice (DRY) way to map my model class to the sql row.
Right now I have a global $TasksColumns and always check that indexes are present:

```
$TasksColumnId = "Id";
$TasksColumnState = "State";
$TasksColumns = [ 
        $TasksColumnId,
        "Summary",
        "Description",
        $TasksColumnState,
        "Estimation",//EstimateDuration
        "Actual",//Duration
        "FixVersion" 
        // Add Rank
        // Add Priority
];
```

And then manually check in code:

```
$task -> Id = $task -> valueIfExistsKeyInArray("Id", $IdSummaryDescriptionStateEstimationActualFixVer);
        $task -> Summary = $task -> valueIfExistsKeyInArray("Summary", $IdSummaryDescriptionStateEstimationActualFixVer);
```

What is a better way to accomplish this? (So I won't have to touch all the code when adding a new SQL column)

Thanks

Comment: `@"Id"` is the Objective-C way to write a string (`NSString`), in PHP you can use either single or double quotes, and you don't add the `@` operator at all (in PHP, `@` is the error suppressor). It also looks as though you don't really _have_ a model in the traditional sense of the word. Just look at existing DBALs out there (Doctrine is the most popular), and use that. It's going to be a lot faster than writing your own, probably too limited, abstraction layer

Comment: Thanks for the info, edited out "@". It was the iOS reflex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).
It's a framework for mapping database rows to php classes.

[Here on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctrine_%28PHP%29) are some examples. This example is copied from wikipedia:

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = "john1";
$user->password = "doe";
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
echo "The user with id $user->id has been saved.";
```

Here is the [Doctrine tutorial](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html). Retrieving objects is also easy (example from the tutorial) :

```
$reporter = $entityManager->find("User", $theReporterId);
```

But you can also perform more complex queries for retrieving objects.